# Service runner-XXX probably didn't start properly

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

There are a lot of answers about this topic, but I cannot find a solution to my problem here my log:

```
Waiting for services to be up and running...
*** WARNING: Service runner-hgz7smm8-project-3-concurrent-0-c2b622f72cceadc3-docker-0 probably didn't start properly.
Health check error:
service "runner-hgz7smm8-project-3-concurrent-0-c2b622f72cceadc3-docker-0-wait-for-service" timeout
Health check container logs:
Service container logs:
2021-12-07T16:13:47.326235886Z mount: permission denied (are you root?)
2021-12-07T16:13:47.326275450Z Could not mount /sys/kernel/security.
2021-12-07T16:13:47.326284427Z AppArmor detection and --privileged mode might break.
```

My docker version inside the runner:

```
root@gitlab-runner-2:~# docker -v
Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu5.1
```

Gitlab-runner:

```
root@gitlab-runner-2:~# gitlab-runner -v
Version:      14.5.1
Git revision: de104fcd
Git branch:   14-5-stable
GO version:   go1.13.8
Built:        2021-12-01T15:41:35+0000
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Runner is an **LXD** container running inside **PROXMOX** and is configured like this with "docker" executor:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "gitlab-runner-2"
  url = "http://gitlab.XXXXXX.com"
  token = "XXXXXXXXXX"
  executor = "docker"
  pre_build_script = "export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2375"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

Any advices?

Comment: What have you tried so far? The error message around permissions denied is pretty explicit; have you ensured your gitlab-runner user has appropriate permissions?

Comment: Hi @Patrick, thanks for your reply. So far I checked if the overlay module was loaded and I set privileged = true and add the pre_build_script value, becasue at the end of the script I have another problem to contact the registry, but this is a different problem. I'll try to reinstall a new runner just to restart clean

Comment: Got it. It sounds like you haven't attempted to disable SELinux yet (which is what usually causes this error). Try running `setenforce 0` as root to set SELinux to permission mode (since I see you're on the root user already), and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick for the tadvice, but unfortunately I don't have SELinux installed in my ubuntu LXC container

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I've achieved, for *GitLab 14.10*, to solve those Warnings/Errors was to perform the following changes.

On *gitlab-runner* *config.toml*:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "runnertothehills"
  url = "https://someexample.com/"
  token = "aRunnerToken"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    image = "docker:20.10.14"
    privileged = true
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache:/cache", "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/builds:/builds"]
    group = 1000
    environment = ["DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG={\"auths\":{\"some.docker.registry.com:12345\":{\"auth\":\"AdockerLoginToken=\"}}}"]
    extra_hosts = ["one.extra.host.com:100.111.120.231"]
```

The main configuration here is the *docker* executor and the volumes mount point  "*/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock*".

In *.gitlab-ci.yml* instead of using

```
service: docker:dind
```

Use docker commands directly.

Example:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - docker login -u myuser -p my_password
```

This solved the following problems:

> ** WARNING: Service runner-3tm987o3-project-131-concurrent-0-ce49f8u8c582bf56-docker-0
> probably didn't start properly.

The problem of *docker group not found*

> 2022-05-23T14:24:57.167991289Z time="2022-05-23T14:24:57.167893989Z"
> level=warning msg="could not change group /var/run/docker.sock to
> docker: group docker not found"

and

> 2022-05-23T14:24:57.168164288Z failed to load listeners: can't create
> unix socket /var/run/docker.sock: device or resource busy